# Template for intranet portal free download 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-template

We need to create an intranet portal and I need a free good template to use which has almost everything  an intranet portal has .

Is there any site which I can download it?

Comment: Please tag your SharePoint version.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not look like WordPress to can find  more template that will match your requirements, So it's recommended to build your own template based on your business requirements that require

- Web Designer to brand your site and its master page,
- SharePoint developer to Customize and develop web part ,workflow .. etc .

You can also check a free

- SharePoint 2010 template [here](http://blog.sharepointengine.com/2011/09/5-free-sharepoint-templates.html) , 
  [Free SharePoint 2010 Sites Templates](https://sp2010teamplates.codeplex.com/)
- SharePoint 2013 check [this](http://www.topsharepoint.com/themes)